# How to write a Python dictionary in JSON format?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to write a dictionary in the JSON format like so:

```
cpu = dict [{'ts':"00:00:00",'values':[3,4,5,67,3,34,2,34]},{'ts':"00:00:11",'values':[2,3,4,5,6,3,4]}]
```

How can I write it in such a format?

Comment: `dict[...]` won't work normally as `dict` is a built-in type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an inbuilt json module which can be used to convert dictionaries to json format.

so:

```
import json

json.dumps({'a':1,'b':2}) #this will return a string with your dict in json format.

#'{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
```

Here's [a link](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) incase you want to learn more about the module and explore other functions.

Hope that helps!

Comment: why are you calling `dumps` on the result of a call to `dumps`? If you're doing it for a reason, your answer will be better if you explain the reason.

Comment: oops.. sorry, i made a mistake in copying and pasting the code, i hope it did not cause much distress!

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), bundled with Python:

```
import json

json.dumps(cpu)
```

Comment: @tbaror: Just trying to understand and improve my answers: Why did you change what answer you mark as accepted?

Answer (score 2):

**simplejson** (or json), is a built in python library,quite useful for this purpose.

```
>>> d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
>>> import simplejson

>>> # To get a JSON string representation
>>> simplejson.dumps(d)

>>> # To directly add the JSON data to a file
>>> simplejson.dump(d,open("json_data.txt",'w'))
```

There are more interesting possibilities, like sorting the keys before dumping to JSON:

```
>>> print(simplejson.dumps({"c": 3, "b": 2, "a": 1}, sort_keys=True))
```

A link to the latest docs - [here](http://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: AFAIK *simplejson* is a slightly more optmized form of the *json* library with the same set of functions.